# How to handle a button click that hides the soft keyboard in Android?

Tags: android

Android Studio 2.3, Android 4.3, Galaxy Nexus.

Screenshot:
[image]

I want the selected button (when clicked) to hide soft keyboard.

Questions:

1. What is the name of this button?
2. How to handle a click of this button in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the back button being pressed by using the following method:

```
// When not using fragments
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {  
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

The code inside the onBackPressed method was found here; [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

```
// When using a fragment
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            // Check if no view has focus:
            View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {  
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Comment: I need to handle back button in Fragment. Fragment not has method "onBackPressed"

Comment: Okay i will look into solutions for that. In the mean time accept my edit so other users can see that a fragment is being used

Comment: When keyboard is show and I click back button the method "onKey(...)" not call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onKeyPreIme` method to handle click of the button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    return true;
}
```